# PSPELL: dictionary file not in proper format

Tags: windows-xp, spellcheck

I am trying to get **PSPELL 0.5.3** to work (i use Apache 2.2.12). I used the **latest win32** installer and installed the **latest german and english dictionaries** from the GNU page.

Now when executing this test snippet

```
3    function testSpell($pspell_link) {
4       echo pspell_check($pspell_link, “testt”) ? 'OK' : 'NOT OK';
5    }
6    
7    $pspell_link = pspell_new('de');
8    testSpell($pspell_link);
```

to see if PSPELL is working correctly i get:

**Warning: pspell_new() [function.pspell-new]: PSPELL couldn't open the dictionary. reason: The file "C:\Programme\Aspell\dict/de-only.rws" is not in the proper format. in ...\check.php  on line 7**

What can be done to get it into the **right format** so that i can use **PSPELL**?

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://www.oblius.com/blog/view.php?ID=116), accuracy not guaranteed in the least:

> Another common problem with ASpell on
>   win32 is the error message:
>
> <filename> is not in the proper format.
>
> This can be resolved by converting all the files in the "Program Files\ASpelldata" directory from DOS to unix format. Search google for dos2unix.exe and you will find a utility that can do it. This will resolve the error.

Alternately, you can do it with a bit of PHP; just preg_replace between "\n" and "\r\n" (depending on which direction you're converting) across the whole file.

Comment: already tried that, but it did not change anything